# adapter for ODB2 device

Tags: obd-ii, fiat, punto

i have a car:

> "fiat punto street 2016".

I just bought a device from ebay that can give me some informations and errors status, the problems is that the device has an interface OBD2 and it's totally different from the plug-in of the car.
In the car is yellow and smaller of OBD2, I would like to ask for a part seller, but kind of adapter can I ask?

According to this website, my car should be OBD2 compatible

Comment: Can you upload a photograph of the connector in the car?

Comment: here the image : https://y78i.imgup.net/odb25343.jpg
 at first look, it seems odb2 uhm :-/

Comment: That definitely looks like an OBD2 port.  What does the adaptor look like?  It doesn't have any bent pins does it?

Comment: What device did you buy? All new Fiat cars have that yellow and black OBDII connector, so that end is fine.

Comment: yes, it's true, it's compatible! i had just to push a little bit more
thank everyone, it's work